# React-router-dom navigate not rendering page

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am working on an app using useNavigate to go from page to page but am having trouble. Currently, the button click will cause the url to update, but the corresponding page doesn't render. Any help as to what I'm doing wrong?

Here is my button component:

```
import Fab from '@material-ui/core/Fab';
import AddIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Add';
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const FabButton = () => {
    let navigate = useNavigate();
    
    return (
        <div >
             <Fab 
                onClick={() => navigate(`/add`)}>  
                <AddIcon />      
            </Fab>
        </div>   
    )
};

export default FabButton;
```

My App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import history from '../history';
import AddPage from './AddPage';
import HomePage from './HomePage';

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <Router location={history.location} navigator={history} >
          <Routes >
            <Route exact path="/add" element={ <AddPage title="One Rep - Add" /> } ></Route>
            <Route exact path="/" element={ <HomePage title="One Rep - Home" /> } ></Route>
          </Routes>
        </Router>
      )
    }
};

export default App;
```

My history.js:

```
import { createHashHistory } from 'history'; 

export default createHashHistory();
```

My AddPage.js:

```
export default AddPage;

import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Header from '../components/Header';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { TextField, Button, InputAdornment } from '@material-ui/core';

const AddPage = () => {
    const [moveData, setMoveData] = useState({ movementName:'', movementWeight: '' });
    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <Header title={"Add Movement"} />
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} >
                    <div>
                        <TextField 
                            name="movementName"
                            variant="outlined"
                            label="Movement Name" 
                            style={{ width:200 }}
                            value={moveData.movementName}
                            onChange={(e) => setMoveData({ ...moveData, movementName: e.target.value })}
                        />
                        <TextField
                            name="movementWeight" 
                            variant="outlined"
                            label="One Rep Max"
                            style={{ width:200 }} 
                            value={moveData.movementWeight}
                            InputProps={{endAdornment: <InputAdornment position="end">lb</InputAdornment>}}
                            onChange={(e) => setMoveData({ ...moveData, movementWeight: e.target.value })}
                        />
                    </div>
                        <div>
                        <Button 
                            variant="contained" 
                            type="submit" 
                            fullWidth >
                            Submit
                        </Button>
                        </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default AddPage;
```

I am using react-router-dom ^6.3.0

Comment: Could you please update this post to include the code for AddPage component assuming that is the page refusing to load?

Comment: Does the `AddPage` component load if you manually navigate to `"/add"`? What is rendering this `FabButton` component? Where is `FabButton` being rendered?

Comment: Additionally, does the AddPage component every load, if you make it the main page does it break or does the page load fine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In react router v6+ you should use `BrowserRouter` instead of `Router`. You can see an example in their [documentation](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview)

So, in your case it should look like this

```
   <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route
          exact
          path="/add"
          element={<AddPage title="One Rep - Add" />}
        ></Route>
        <Route
          exact
          path="/"
          element={<HomePage title="One Rep - Home" />}
        ></Route>
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
```

[Here is minimal reproduction](https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-keldysh-5x4l7n?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: OP is using a low-level router with a hash history. The `BrowserRouter` component isn't very relevant here.

Comment: @DrewReese If thats the case then OP could use `HashRouter`, but I agree that adjustents would need to be made.

Comment: That may be true, however, if they are using the custom history object elsewhere in the code the `HashRouter` won't work either as it uses its own internal history context reference.

Comment: I believe this makes sense, I see Op marked question as answered so I believe this one is resolved.

Comment: Sure, completely ditching the hash history and low-level `Router` and replacing with the `BrowserRouter` *could* be a way to make stuff work. I guess we'll never know why OP's code wasn't working unless they provide a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). ‍♂️